# Typo in ad for Braintree

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, spelling

This ad has surfaced on SO.

[image]

The drone is a [Parrot *Bebop* Drone](http://www.parrot.com/usa/products/bebop-drone/?gclid=COv5r_DA6cMCFQeDfgodsbgAgQ) instead of bepop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice catch!

Working on a fix right now.

Thank you!

Comment: btw, doesn't this belong to MSO rather than MSE?...

Comment: @yo' I believe that ads can be used on more than one SE site.  Hence the posting here. Perhaps I am wrong however.

Comment: @yo' The campaign is currently targeting other sites in addition to SO, so this is probably the proper home for this question.

Comment: @stevvve Ok, I didn't know, thanks :)

Comment: @yo' Haha I'd be impressed if you did!

Comment: "working on a fix" - meaning contacting the company and asking them to fix... no? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I expect that darn typo to be gone very soon! :-)